# Does the TEPMPORARY function from IDL has an analogue in Python?

Tags: python, optimization, ram, idl-programming-language

In the Interactive Data Language (IDL) there is the function `TEMPORARY`:

https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/TEMPORARY.html

This function allows things like the following:

```
A = TEMPORARY(B)
```

Which copies the information from `B` into `A` without doubling the used memory. That is, if `A` amounts to 1GB of RAM, the task above does not need a computer with 2GB of RAM and it can be executed in a computer with 1GB of RAM.

I was wondering if such a function exists in Python.

Comment: So `B` is a reference to `A` - or is there something like copy-on-write?

Comment: The exact semantics of `TEMPORARY()` are fundamentally impossible to duplicate in Python, as it involves changing the value of the variable passed to it.  In Python, only *values* are ever passed to functions, there is no access to the variable that value came from (assuming that it even did come from a variable, rather than something like a literal or an expression).